# overflow-y: auto & width: 100% in Google's Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

`width:100%; overflow: auto; /* or overflow-y:auto or scroll */` works fine in all browsers but Google's Chrome. It is my understanding that this is a bug, however, I cannot find any workaround. The demo is available here:

http://anuary.com/#!/home

Screenshot (FF & Google Chrome):

[image]

Comment: maybe it's because I'm on mobile and the images are small but I can't spot the difference

Comment: Do you have Google Chrome on your mobile? Have you take a look at the screenshot? See the red thing? it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Oh, you meant the red thing, I thought that was just part of the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the margin-left on #body.

Chrome does have some problems with margins and floated elements, but this fix doesn't appear to harm your layout.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't notice this myself, though, yes, it seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed ! Remove the margin-left from the #body styles.

```
position: relative;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 100%;
background: cyan;
```